# Compiler error when including <chrono> in a CUDA program - even with --std=c++11

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors, cuda, nvcc

I try to measure time in a CUDA program.

For that purpose I want to use:

```
#include <chrono>
```

I receive an error though:

```
error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

I have tried to inlcude the options `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14`, `-std=c++17`.

None of them worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

That message isn't coming from the CUDA toolchain, it is coming from gcc (and a rather old version of gcc, probably 4.3). And the message tells you *exactly* what to do -- you need to pass `-std=c++0x` as an option to gcc. Any host compiler options are passed from nvcc via the `-Xcompiler` option so

```
$ nvcc -Xcompiler="--std=c++0x" .....
```

should solve the problem of the compiler refusing to import `<chrono>`.

Comment: This gives me a huge error list. Part of it saying: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/exception_ptr.h(114): error: copy constructor for class "std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr" may not have a parameter of type "std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr"

//...//

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/chrono(184): error: space required between adjacent ">" delimiters of nested template argument lists (">>" is the right shift operator)

Error limit reached.
Compilation terminated.
`

Comment: So your compiler is supplied with a broken `chrono` implementation, or you are using it incorrectly. The official documentation for GCC says that official C++11 support was introduced in gcc 4.7. You are using gcc 4.4. None of this has anything to do with CUDA

Comment: You are right. I have `gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to @talonmies's correct answer, and caution you to consider carefully whether or not you actually want to write your own code to do the timing. CUDA offers a profiler for timing kernels and CUDA Runtime API calls; and you can also use its C(ish) API to mark segments and points on the program's timeline.

nVIDIA's Mark Harris wrote a [blog post/tutorial](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-nvprof-your-handy-universal-gpu-profiler/) about using the profile, you might want to check it out.